# Animate translate on scroll

Tags: html, css, scroll, translate-animation

I am trying to animate translate(X, Y) when a user scrolls. I have all the scrolling functionality implemented, it just looks horrible as the switch is instantaneous.

I cannot seem to figure out how I can animate the translate.

On load, my container has the value `-webkit-transform: translate(0%, 0%);`, to go to the second 'slide' it'll be changed to `-webkit-transform: translate(0%, -100%);`

I am just doing this through jQuery:

```
 $('.container').css({"transform":"translate(0%,-" + positionY + "%)"});
```

I want to replicate the animation here: http://www.apple.com/uk/iphone-5s/

(Note: I use translate(x, y) for moving side ways later on.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [CSS `transition` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) to get a smooth effect.

```
.container {
    transition: transform 1s;
}
```

(You also need vendor prefixes to target all browsers.)

See also this MDN article for more examples and a tutorial: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions

Comment: Sigh. It's always the easy ones that catch you out. -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 2s worked flawlessly, thank you very much for your time.